# Likelihood calculation in Particle Filtering

Tags: bayesian, particle-filter

I have a doubt with likelihood calculation in particle filtering.

In my understanding the particle filter consists of the following steps

1. Generate particles from initial point
2. Propagate through system model ($X_p(k) = A*X_f(k-1) + Q$) 
   (I am generating Gaussian noise and adding to state equation based on $Q$ for each particle)
3. Weight update using likelihood calculation
   For likelihood calculation I need measurement from sensor (with Gaussian noise) and predicted measurement

   For the predicted measurements, I have to use the measurement equation
   $$y = H*x + R$$  For each particle I have to calculate corresponding $y$ value.

   **Should I generate Gaussian noise based of R for every particle while calculating predicted measurement y?**

In the Kalman filter  we use  $y = H*x$ ( since we are calculating mean), what should I do in particle filter...?

Answer (score 2):

Just compute the likelihood of data given the particles.
For 1-d

```
normpdf(y(k),x_particles,standard_dev_of_noise)
```

For multi-dimensional case

```
mvnpdf(y(k),H*x_particles,R)
```

These will be your weights. Then get the resampling indices according to your favorite resampling algorithm and resample your particles.

Answer (score 1):

Additions to the above answer:

- The likelihoods are not your weights. You need to multiply them with your weight at time k-1.
- Also you should normalize the weights before resampling.